# SQL / коррелированный подзапрос

Tags: sql, sql-server

Является ли мой подзапрос коррелированным?

```
SELECT ContactName FROM Customers
WHERE CustomerID IN
(SELECT CustomerID FROM Orders
WHERE ShipperID = 3);
```

Мне нужно придумать какой-то коррелированный подзапрос с `SELECT` , `UPDATE` , `DELETE`
Запросы создаю на учебной базе w3schools.

Comment: Нет. Это не коррелированный подзапрос.

Comment: почему? и как его сделать таковым?

Comment: https://www.sqlservertutorial.org/sql-server-correlated-subquery/

Answer (score 0):

Коррелированным называется подзапрос, использующий значения полей источника данных внешнего запроса. Например

```sql
SELECT ContactName 
FROM Customers
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM Orders
               WHERE Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID 
                 AND Orders.ShipperID = 3);
```

Comment: а зачем мы используем NULL?

Comment: @mksmbbk Не нравится NULL - используйте любое другое значение, константу любого типа или выражение. EXISTS вообще не получает выражения, указанного в SELECT подзапроса, он проверяет только сам факт существования записи, факт того, что выходное выражение нужно было бы получать, не будь снаружи этого EXISTS..

Comment: То бишь, согласно этого запроса я получаю список ContactName у которых ShipperID = 3 ? Мы обращаемся сначала в Orders сравниваем значения между таблицами Customers и Orders, и потом выполняется внешний запрос который выдает нам список  ContactName ?

Comment: @mksmbbk Нет, наоборот. Для каждой записи из Customers проверяется, существует ли в Orders запись с тем же CustomerID и ShipperID = 3. Возвращаются только те записи из Customers, для которых хотя бы одна такая запись существует. При наличии индекса `Orders (ShipperID, CustomerID)`. Такой запрос гораздо эффективнее, чем WHERE IN, а при низком проценте соответствия он к тому же обычно эффективнее JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо ув. Akina за помощь с решение задачи. Ответ верный.

```
SELECT ContactName 
FROM Customers
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
               FROM Orders
               WHERE Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID 
                 AND Orders.ShipperID = 3);
```

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Пожалуйста, примите во внимание, в разделе справки: [Почему и как удаляются некоторые ответы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), кроме всего прочего, сказано: _имеют формат «спасибо»_ Это сообщение, пожалуйста, удалите.